# Typescript: push not available on custom typed array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Using Javascript with Typescript (v1.4.1) I have a custom type as follows:

```
interface WordDataForQuestion {
    question : {
        id : number;
        vocab : string;
        comment : string;
    };
    possibleAnswers : {
        [index : number] : {
            id : number;
            vocab : string;
            comment : string;
        }
    };
}
```

Now I want to push an element in the array `possibleAnswers`

```
nextWordData.possibleAnswers.push(
    {
        id : vocabs[index].id,
        vocab : vocabs[index].voc_t,
        comment : vocabs[index].com_t
    }
);
```

but it gives me the following error:

```
exercise.ts(69,42): error TS2339: Property 'push' does not exist on type '{ [index: number]: { id: number; vocab: string; comment: string; }; }'.
```

I don't understand what is wrong - `possibleAnswers` should be a JavaScript array here which supports the push-operation. Am I not right?

Comment: Take a look at your interface definition -- you're defining an array-like object, not an actual array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. You did define it as an object with an indexer. Not as an array, see example below

```
possibleAnswers : {
        id : number;
        vocab : string;
        comment : string;
}[];
```

Comment: Thanks al lot - it is working now. I'm really wondering because I didn't see this information on http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#interfaces-array-types, there they do not put the [] after the interface definition ...

Comment: @mbader: it's actually under "basic types": http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#basic-types-array