# Define mandantory Datatype for Arrays in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript

I want to define a jsonArray and also the datatypes, which have to be used.

My first approach was this one hear:

```
felder = [{
    elementId: string,  // elementId: ''  would work
    value: string,
    inputType: string
  }];

  constructor() {
    this.felder.push({elementId: 'ID1', value: 'First', inputType: 'input'});
    this.felder.push({elementId: 'ID2', value: 'Second', inputType: 'dropdown'});
    this.felder.push({elementId: 'ID3', value: 'Third', inputType: 'checkbox'});
  }
```

But it does not work. The error message is:

string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

I understand the error but cannot find a solution. How can I define a must-used datatype?

Thanks & Best Regards

Comment: [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49174477/push-to-array-of-interface-type) an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an interface:

```
interface MyInterface {
  elementId: string;
  value: string;
  inputType: string;
}

class MyClass {
  public felder: MyInterface[] = [];

  constructor() {
    this.felder.push({elementId: 'ID1', value: 'First', inputType: 'input'});
    this.felder.push({elementId: 'ID2', value: 'Second', inputType: 'dropdown'});
    this.felder.push({elementId: 'ID3', value: 'Third', inputType: 'checkbox'});
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. To be clear for other searching people: to be able to push the arrayelements, the MyInterface[] line has to initialised with an empty array: felder: MyInterface[] = [];